# I'm having problems during string formatting

Tags: python, string

I'm learning python. I was learning strings `.format` method to assign characters and I'm getting this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-5-ccb10b41da2a>", line 1
    print('the {d} {k} {r}' .format (d='dark' k='knight' r='rises'))
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are missing commas inside the brackets after the word format. Try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing commas inside the brackets after the word format. Try this

```
print('the {d} {k} {r}' .format (d='dark', k='knight', r='rises'))
```

Comment: @ ConfusionMatrix Thanks a lot!